# Not able to reflect the setting of auto_path in TCL when running from another machine

Tags: tcl, environment-variables, sh

Installed tcllib on my machine under /usr/local/tools/Unix/tcl_pkgs/tclx/tclX8.4/ and sourced the script below

```
#!/bin/sh
set ::auto_path [linsert $auto_path 0 /usr/local/tools/Unix/tcl_pkgs/tclx/tclX8.4/]
set ::env(TCLLIBPATH) "/usr/local/tools/Unix/tcl_pkgs/tclx/tclX8.4/"
set ::env(ITCL_LIBRARY) "/usr/local/tools/Unix/tcl_pkgs/tclx/tclX8.4/itcl3.4.1/"
```

before the

> **package require Tclx**

instruction to export the tcllib and itcl path, but am not able to get the auto_path set properly. Kept getting the below error when I ever I run my test. The tclIndex is being read from a wrong path.

```
couldn't open "/usr/lib64/tcl8.5/tclIndex": no such file or directory
while executing
"open [file join $dir tclIndex]"
```

Comment: please note that Tclx is not part of the tcllib.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tcl and the shell have different syntaxes for handling variables. Moreover, the `auto_path` is a Tcl variable *only* and is not a shell variable at all. It's built from the contents of various other things (including some values that are baked in during compilation of the Tcl library). One of those things is the `TCLLIBPATH` environment variable, which holds a *Tcl list* (i.e., space-separated list) of directories to put at the front of the `auto_path` when it is built.

There's no point in setting the value of the `TCLLIBPATH` once a Tcl interpreter is running; it has already used it if it was set. Once in your code, you might as well manipulate the `auto_path` itself directly.

From a `/bin/sh` shell script, you set the `TCLLIBPATH` with:

```
export TCLLIBPATH="/usr/local/tools/Unix/tcl_pkgs/tclx/tclX8.4"
```

What's more, *as is usual with shell scripts* you need to make sure you're not setting environment variables in a subshell unless you are using them only in subprocesses of that subshell.